Are efficiency questions valid here?
I have asked the following question which was closed as being the duplicate and never reopened no matter how I tried to stress the difference between it and the quoted one: Adding new variable to a linear regression
The quoted post deals with showing how to get the ols coefficients from the covariance matrix of the features and target. My post instead asks whether anything can be gained by not only having this matrix but in addition the optimal weights for the ols of the subproblem. In my understanding if such approach exists it can be much more efficient than solving the problem anew.
If I asked such question on math.SE I’d be expecting to see the answer that the old weights are redundant, as pure math does not really always have to deal with the efficiency, hence I’ve asked this on the statistics page where I guess people also care about and deal with the practicalities.
So my point is: does it mean I should not expect the questions of the shape “we can solve the problem using A only, but does adding information about B simplify the solution” get answers? By answer I mean either the way/direction how adding information about B (the sub problem weights in this case) helps, or why exactly it does not help.

I don't think there is an underlying policy issue here. Your question was closed and reasons given why. Whether mathSE would treat the question differently, or not, is interesting but immaterial to the decision.

@NickCox I have addressed those reasons and voted to reopen which never happened. The comments I keep on getting is: my question was answered in the cited post, yet the latter does not address efficiency which is at the core of my question. It’s really getting hard for me to see why this point is being missed

I can't add to (and certainly have nothing to subtract from) the well-informed comments you have already had.

@NickCox just so I understand what you mean, you do think that the cited post answers my question?

No; I am commenting on what you are asking here, which I don't think is well encapsulated by your title. I take the Meta issue to be whether closure of your question was justified. You've not got any full answers here, but the votes show 2 people agreeing with my point and no-one else yet inspired to reply. I appreciate that you will find that frustrating at least.

Your voting to reopen your own closed question does not in itself carry much weight.

I cannot see any reference to "efficiency" in the current version of your question (which, btw, could mean many different things in this context).  Perhaps making additional edits to clarify the thrust of your query might help people appreciate what you're trying to ask.

@whuber the very last sentence in the current version states specifically the word simplest when speaking about using additional information. Would that make any difference if instead I wrote most efficient?

@SBF Simplicity and efficiency are not synonyms. If "efficiency" is what you want to ask about, then you should write that in the question.

... and please give a clear description or definition of what you mean by "efficiency" when you do so, because that term can have very different meanings in this context (e.g., efficiency qua estimator or efficiency in the sense of algorithmic performance).

I think that your question might in principle valid but you haven't explained it very well. Or at least, if I would guess what your question means, then I would say that you are asking:
For the situation where a new feature is added in ordinary least squares regression, is there an algorithm that can use old coefficients to efficiently re-compute new coefficients?
If my interpretation is right, then copy this sentence above into your question to make it more clear.
If my interpretation is wrong, then your question is not easy to follow. At least not to me, and possibly others.

Thank you, I have added this sentence, hopefully this helps. How exactly does this differ from the previous closing sentence, namely: Are there available formulas for how the new OLS weights $(\beta'i){i=0}^{n+1}$ can be computed through the old weights, $C'$ and $\mu'$? I am not interested in expressing $\beta'$ through $C'$ - no doubts this can be done, I wonder what's the simplest way one can obtain $\beta'$ from both $C'$ and $\beta$.

@SBF one difference is that it doesn't contain symbols $\beta$, $C$, $\mu$, superscripts $'$ and brackets $()_{i=0}^{n+1}$. The verbose and mathematical language in your question confused me a lot. You also introduce all those terms in a casual way with mathematical terms like "I have an access to a square covariance matrix $C'$ ". Ok, what sort of covariance matrix? Between which variables and what does the $'$ signify. You say that it's dimension is $n+2$ and I might assume that it is the covariance of the $n$ old features $1$ new feature and $1$ the target....

... so your question comes across like a bombardement with unclear mathematical symbols, while you might just as well pose the question in simple language.

@SBF possibly the matrix is of size (n+3) because you have n original features 1 intercept 1 new feature 1 target (giving n+3 vectors).

@SBF with these type of questions (when thet are unclear),  it already starts going through my kind and I have an idea about solutions like computing the matrix inverse for the problem with n+1 features using the result with the matrix inverse for the problem with n features https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Inversion . However the question is too fuzzy and unclear to me, such that I would like more clarification before composing a complete answer out of that idea.

sure, though in such case I expected requests to clarify notation, though after the review I've just done it should have been clear. But ok, confusion is subjective. I wasn't sure what needs to be done about the question as it was considered unclear as a whole rather than a specific feedback being given to parts of it that were confusing, e.g. notation. Anyways, you've explained it now
